# unity slider should stop going right at certain value

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity sliders should stop going right at a certain value. Example: slider range is (1-10) and I want my slider to stop going right when it reaches slider value = 5. NOTE: Interactable will remain ON.

Please Help!!

Comment: If you want a good answer, you'll have to be more specific than that! What exactly are you trying to achieve? What have you tried? Do you have any sample code, or any debugging information? What classes and functions are you using? Try to act as if you're giving a lecture rather than asking a question, and provide as much information as specifically as possible. Screenshots of your setup, or snippets of your actual code, may help you receive a useful response.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this component to your slider:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Slider))]
public class PartialSlider : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxValue = 5f;
    Slider slider;

    private void Awake()
    {
        slider = GetComponent<Slider>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (slider.value > maxValue) slider.value = maxValue;
    }
}
```

Make sure no other script is setting the slider value after this runs.